# ionic slider no va a la ultima foto automaticamente

Tags: ionic, angular, slider

llevo poco tiempo con ionic y no se si lo que intento hacer se puede hacer, la intencion es que segun el usuario ponga una foto en un slider el slider vaya a la ultima foto puesta automaticamente, tengo este codigo realizado y no se si voy por buen camino

```
<ion-slides pager spaceBetween="10">
  <ion-slide *ngIf="images.length === 0">
    <img src="assets/imgs/not-available-es.png" />
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
    <button ion-button icon-only color="primary" class="remove-image" (click)="removePicture(i)">
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <img [src]="image" class="photo-image">
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

y el ts

```
readThis(inputValue: any): void {
if (inputValue.files[0]) {
  let file: File = inputValue.files[0];
  let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

  myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    this.images.push(myReader.result);
    console.log(this.slides.length());
  }
  myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luján. Has de explicar qué problemas y errores tienes.. Dices que *"no se si voy por buen camino"* y eso no nos aclara nada. Intenta añadir informacion segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tenés que hacer es usar los métodos proveidos por el slide. El que necesitas es `slideTo`. En tu componente tenés que hacer algo como esto

```
readThis(inputValue: any): void {
  if (inputValue.files[0]) {
    let file: File = inputValue.files[0];
    let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
      this.images.push(myReader.result);
      console.log(this.slides.length());
      // ************************
      this.slides.slideTo(this.slides.length() - 1, 500)
      // ************************
    }
    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto me sirvio, aunque el fallo de ahora es que la primera foto que tengo me la lee dos veces como la primera foto